# HTML menu not centered right

Tags: html, menu, center

I finally succeeded in justifying and centering my list, but it does not look centered right at all.
also, it's a dropdown menu and that menu now appears in line for some reason.

it should be online at [link deleted]

```css
  body { margin:0; }

a { color: black; text-decoration: none;}

a:hover { color: black; text-decoration: underline;}

#inhoud { padding:10%; padding-top:4%; }

#menu {
  position:fixed;
  height:auto;
  width: 100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  background-color: f2f2f2;
}

#menu-list{ width:60%; margin:0 auto; }

#menu ul {
  position:relative;
  padding: 0;
  width:75%;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align:justify;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
}

#menu ul:after{
  content:"";
  width:100%;
  display:inline-block;
}

#menu li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align:center;
}

#menu ul ul{
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  top:100%;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  width:150%;
  z-index: 100;
  display: none;
}

#menu ul ul li { width:100%; }

#menu li:hover ul{ display:block; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome</title>

<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="extra.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" href="img/ico.ico" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300|Roboto|Open+Sans:800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />

</head>
<body>

<div id="menu">
<div id="menu-list">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Photoshop</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Illustrator</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Articles</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Inspiration</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>

<div id="inhoud">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a diam lectus. Sed sit amet ipsum mauris. Maecenas congue ligula ac quam viverra nec consectetur ante hendrerit. Donec et mollis dolor. Praesent et diam eget libero egestas mattis sit amet vitae augue. Nam tincidunt congue enim, ut porta lorem lacinia consectetur. Donec ut libero sed arcu vehicula ultricies a non tortor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean ut gravida lorem. Ut turpis felis, pulvinar a semper sed, adipiscing id dolor. Pellentesque auctor nisi id magna consequat sagittis. Curabitur dapibus enim sit amet elit pharetra tincidunt feugiat nisl imperdiet. Ut convallis libero in urna ultrices accumsan. Donec sed odio eros. Donec viverra mi quis quam pulvinar at malesuada arcu rhoncus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. In rutrum accumsan ultricies. Mauris vitae nisi at sem facilisis semper ac in est.
    Vivamus fermentum semper porta. Nunc diam velit, adipiscing ut tristique vitae, sagittis vel odio. Maecenas convallis ullamcorper ultricies. Curabitur ornare, ligula semper consectetur sagittis, nisi diam iaculis velit, id fringilla sem nunc vel mi. Nam dictum, odio nec pretium volutpat, arcu ante placerat erat, non tristique elit urna et turpis. Quisque mi metus, ornare sit amet fermentum et, tincidunt et orci. Fusce eget orci a orci congue vestibulum. Ut dolor diam, elementum et vestibulum eu, porttitor vel elit. Curabitur venenatis pulvinar tellus gravida ornare. Sed et erat faucibus nunc euismod ultricies ut id justo. Nullam cursus suscipit nisi, et ultrices justo sodales nec. Fusce venenatis facilisis lectus ac semper. Aliquam at massa ipsum. Quisque bibendum purus convallis nulla ultrices ultricies. Nullam aliquam, mi eu aliquam tincidunt, purus velit laoreet tortor, viverra pretium nisi quam vitae mi. Fusce vel volutpat elit. Nam sagittis nisi dui.
    Suspendisse lectus leo, consectetur in tempor sit amet, placerat quis neque. Etiam luctus porttitor lorem, sed suscipit est rutrum non. Curabitur lobortis nisl a enim congue semper. Aenean commodo ultrices imperdiet. Vestibulum ut justo vel sapien venenatis tincidunt. Phasellus eget dolor sit amet ipsum dapibus condimentum vitae quis lectus. Aliquam ut massa in turpis dapibus convallis. Praesent elit lacus, vestibulum at malesuada et, ornare et est. Ut augue nunc, sodales ut euismod non, adipiscing vitae orci. Mauris ut placerat justo. Mauris in ultricies enim. Quisque nec est eleifend nulla ultrices egestas quis ut quam. Donec sollicitudin lectus a mauris pulvinar id aliquam urna cursus. Cras quis ligula sem, vel elementum mi. Phasellus non ullamcorper urna.
    Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. In euismod ultrices facilisis. Vestibulum porta sapien adipiscing augue congue id pretium lectus molestie. Proin quis dictum nisl. Morbi id quam sapien, sed vestibulum sem. Duis elementum rutrum mauris sed convallis. Proin vestibulum magna mi. Aenean tristique hendrerit magna, ac facilisis nulla hendrerit ut. Sed non tortor sodales quam auctor elementum. Donec hendrerit nunc eget elit pharetra pulvinar. Suspendisse id tempus tortor. Aenean luctus, elit commodo laoreet commodo, justo nisi consequat massa, sed vulputate quam urna quis eros. Donec vel.
    <br> <br> porno porno

    </p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix this by changing your margin in your css under #menu ul

FROM:

```
margin: 0;
```

TO:

```
margin: auto;
```

This simply tells the list you have in your div#menu to maintain equal margins. This way, if you change your menu in the future it will automatically stay centered.

To make the drop down categories stack instead of displaying inline change

```
#menu ul ul{
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  top:100%;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  width:150%;
  z-index: 100;
  display: none;
}
```

TO:

```
#menu ul ul{
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  top:100%;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  width:100px;
  z-index: 100;
  display: none;
}
```

By making div#menu ul ul 100px wide you are forcing each

on to the next line. A neater way to do it would be to actually style the

to be a specific width that is the same as the width of div#menu ul ul.

Comment: my pleasure. I realized you also asked about subcategories displaying inline and edited my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

Your menu-list div is centered. The text inside the menu is not. The list elements are left-aligned. 
Try this:

```
#menu ul {
  border: 0 none;
  display: block;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center; // The justify declaration was pushing li's to the left.
  width: 75%;
}
```

You will need to pad your list elements to spread them out.

Answer (score 0):

So I fixed it myself, the #menu ul had a width of 75% which made it go to the left. after making it 100% it was perfectly centered. Thanks anyways